# Trouble calling JavaScript function on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, onload

I have a javascript function that i have named refreshProjects(), what it does is filter a dropdownlist depending on what was selected in a previous dropdownlist. But i need to also filter my list direcktly after the page has finishd loading.

I have tried using the code window.onload = refreshProjects(id) with no sucsses, but onload workes when i use  window.onload = alert('This page has finished loading!'), so i know that part off the script works. So how do i call a javascript function on load, i thought that it would be simple but evrything i tried have failed.

```
@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = refreshProjects(id);   <-- Problem

    $("#ddCustomers").change(function () {
        refreshProjects($(this).val());
    });
    function refreshProjects(id) {
        var projects = $("#ddProjects");
        $.get('@Url.Action("FilterProjects","TimeEntry")', { customerId: id },
        function (result) {
            // clear the dropdown
            projects.empty();

            //Add a deafult "null" value
            $("#ddProjects").get(0).options[0] = new Option("[ - No project - ]", "-1"); 

            // rebuild the dropdown
            $.each(result, function (i, e) {
                projects.append($('<option/>').text(e.Text).val(e.Value));
            });
        });
    }</script>
}
```

This is for MVC 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `window.onload = refreshProjects(id);` to:

```
window.onload = function() { refreshProjects($("#ddCustomers").val()); };
```

Onload expects a callback function. You were directly executing refreshProjects() and setting the return value as the onload.

But since you seem to be using jQUery, you could do the following:

```
$(function() {
    refreshProjects($("#ddCustomers").val());
});
```

This will execute refreshProjects when the document is ready (which actually is before window load).

Comment: This did not work, id is from the selected customer in the dropdownlist ddcustomers and it is used to determin what projekts should be included in the dropdownlist ddProjekts.

Comment: Okay, then id needs to be `$("#ddCustomers").val()`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    refreshProjects(id);
});
```

This should work aswell if you are using jQuery.

Comment: What exactly did not work? The automation should work, but I guess you are trying to access the value of a DOM element with your argument "id", aren't you? Try to use `refreshProjects($('#ddcustomers').val());` or whatever value you use to represent the id.